# How to quickly load two distinct areas into postGIS without using --append flag?

Tags: postgis, osm2pgsql

I have two distinct / non-overlapping areas that I wish to load into a postGIS database.

The trouble is that once one area is loaded, it becomes painfully slow to load the second area using the `--append` flag. (1.8k/s vs. the 200+k/s for the initial import using the `--create` flag.)

Is there a way to load two separate `osm.pbf` files into the same database tables without `osm2psql` checking for diffs in the process?

Comment: I suspect the append may be slower because after the initial import indexes were created. If you delay the construction of indexes until all your data has been imported into PostGIS, you won't see this slow-down. What are the complete `osm2pgsql` commands you are using?

Comment: Thanks for this. I haven't yet tried it as I ended up using `osmconvert` to merge the areas prior to importing, which worked quite nicely. Though I suspect some time or another I'll have an opportunity to give the non-index method a go.

Comment: Dropping the spatial indexes will make `--append` slightly faster, but not anything close to the `--create` speed. Because there is no other existing data, `--create` can load data in a faster way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best method is, as you've found, osmconvert, or osmosis.

With osmconvert, you can merge two files with `osmconvert <(osmconvert a.pbf --out-o5m) <(osmconvert b.pbf --out-o5m) -o merged.pbf`

or, if you want to use o5m as an intermediate format, `osmconvert <(osmconvert a.pbf --out-o5m) <(osmconvert b.pbf --out-o5m) -o merged.o5m`

With osmosis, a suitable command line would be `osmosis --read-pbf-fast a.pbf --read-pbf-fast b.pbf --merge --write-pbf merged.pbf`

You can then use a normal osm2pgsql command line to import, like `osm2pgsql -d gis merged.pbf` or `osm2pgsql -d gis --slim --drop merged.pbf`.